# How can I check if a number is in scientific notation with exponential part?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to check if a number is represented in scientific notation? i.e with exponential part 10<sup>6</sup> is represented as 1e6.

I have a case in my code when adding or multiply integers, when usual number gets converted scientific notation when represented.

Comment: No *number* "is exponential". A number is just a number. A *very large number* may be presented to you in scientific notation in some situations to keep its representation short; the number itself is still a number though.

Comment: *"How can I check if number is exponential?"* What you're referring to isn't a property of the number -- numbers are just numbers -- but of the default way they're converted to string. You can control how they're converted to string. But unless you're doing that, you don't need to worry about it. This seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you care? Are you trying to format the number?

Comment: For example, in my locale (here in the UK), `(10000000*100000000000000000).toLocaleString()` gives me the string `1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000` (as opposed to `1e+24`, which is what `toString` gives). In some other locales, those `,` might be `.` or spaces, and/or the grouping of digits might be different. (You can specify a locale: `.toLocaleString("en-US")`, for instance.)

Comment: As per previous answers, a number is just represented as exponential, the number represented as exponentials are the ones `>= 1e20`

Comment: I believe you want to verify if a number is in Scientific notation. It might be better for you to use a regular expression that can verify if a number is in Scientific notation. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/display-numbers-in-scientific-exponential-notation-f85a96c0-18a1-4249-81c3-e934cd2aae25

Answer (score 6):

Convert to a string and check for `e`.

```js
let num = 10000000;
console.log(num.toString().includes('e'));

num *= 100000000000000000;
console.log(num.toString().includes('e'));
```

Comment: Convenient that neither `"NaN"` nor `"Infinity"` has an "e" in it. ;-)